# WPF Binding Complex Object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a model implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` like below.  Binding name and city to a label is easy.  But I am having trouble binding Players to a datagrid.  Does anyone have any tips?  (This is all readonly information.)

```
public class Team : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private string _city;
    private List<Player> _players;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    public string City
    {
        get { return _city; }
    }

    public List<Player> Players
    {
        get { return _players; }
    }

}
public class Player
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Please show your XAML code for your `DataGrid`. What have you tried?

Comment: you connot compile this, I edited your code, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Who knows what I thought that I was doing.  But it is working now.  Here is the ItemSource:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Players}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Team class, you must Implement INotifypropertyChanged like this :

```
  public class Team : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _city;
        private List<Player> _players;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
        }

        public string City
        {
            get { return _city; }
        }

        public List<Player> Players
        {
            get { return _players; }
            set { 
                _players =value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Players");
            }
        }


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

    }
    public class Player
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Set the DataContext of your MainWindow by an instance on Team class Like This :

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new Team
            {
                Players = new List<Player>()
                { 
                    new Player{ ID=1, FirstName="Mohammed", LastName="Ali" },
                    new Player{ ID=2, FirstName="Paul", LastName="Oshain" },
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

And finaly make a good binding in your XAML (your MainWindow); like this :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Players}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"  Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name"  Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
          </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```